# Why empty string is on every string?

Tags: python, string

For example:

```
>>> s = 'python'
>>> s.index('')
0
>>> s.index('p')
0
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is because the substring of length 0 starting at index 0 in `'python'` is equal to the empty string:

```
>>> s[0:0]
''
```

Of course *every* substring of length zero of any string is equal to the empty string.

Answer (score 6):

You can see `"python"` as "the empty string, followed by a `p`, followed by fifteen more empty strings, followed by a `y`, followed by forty-two empty strings, ...".

Point being, empty strings don't take any space, so there's no reason why it should *not* be there.

The `index` method could be specified like this:

> `s.index(t)` returns a value `i` such that `s[i : i+len(t)]` is equal to `t`

If you substitute the empty string for `t`, this reads: "returns a value `i` such that `s[i:i]` is equal to `""`". And indeed, the value `0` is a correct return value according to this specification.