# Why python's interprets not empty strig's objects as logical False?

Tags: python

I don't understand why not empty strings are False, same like empty strings. I think that collection of characters is much something than less. What is a root of python purpose in this case?

```
>>> "" in 'fdsa'
True
>>> '' in ''
True
>>> 'asdf' in ''
False
>>> 'adsf' is True
False
```

Comment: "why not empty strings are False, same like empty strings". What on earth does this mean?

Comment: @DavidRobinson, OP's asking "why are non-empty strings False, the same as empty strings are?" English is much harder than Python for beginners. (OP's premise is mistaken, which isn't helping matters.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't quite get your question.  You are using two operators here:

1. `in` for strings checks whether the first string is a substring of the second.  [The empty string is considered a substring of every other string.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5206477/279627)
2. `is` tests for object identity and returns `True` if both operators are the same object.  `'adsf'` and `True` clearly aren't the same object, so you get `False`.

None of those two operators are related to interpreting strings in a Boolean context – something your question also seems to touch on.  A Boolean context would be the condition of an `if` statement, for example.  In a Boolean context, empty strings are treated as `False`, and non-empty strings as `True`.  You can see how an object behaves in a Boolean context by using `bool(obj)`.

Answer (score 2):

Note that if you want to see what the boolean value of a string is, you can call the `bool()` function on it, like so:

```
>>> bool('')
False
>>> bool('asdf')
True
```

The keyword `in` ([docs](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange)) will test if an element is in a sequence -- I don't think it's what you want.