# Understanding the output of the s.count("") method

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

Suppose that we have a string:

```
s= "He ate my food"
```

and I use:

```
>>>s.find("")
0 
>>>s.index("")
0
>>>s.count("")
15
>>> len(s)
14
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: you are counting an empty string, use `s.count(' ')`

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5206466/why-empty-string-is-on-every-string

Comment: What exactly is surprising you about the results you got?

Comment: @JimFasarakisHilliard I think they're asking why a string contains an empty string and why `str.count()` `return`s `15`

Comment: @Chris_Rands yes this is my question

Comment: @Chris_Rands Martijn's answer covers that too. I don't believe there's a need to say the same things here.

Comment: @JimFasarakisHilliard Agreed the dupe is spot on