# Why does the following Python 3 sentence returns "True"? ---> '' in 'abc'

Tags: python

'''
Here it goes (in interpreter):

> > > a=''
> > >
> > > a in '12345'

True

'''

Answer (score 1):

The empty string is in all strings, that's why it evaluates to True.

```
>>> a=' '
>>> a in '12345'
>>> False
```

vs

```
>>> a=''
>>> a in '12345'
>>> True
```

Answer (score 0):

You always get an empty string from any string. Reason:

```py
>>>a=''
>>>b='12345'
>>>a in b
True
>>>b[0:0] # == a
''
```

[You can read more in here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5206466/why-empty-string-is-on-every-string)