# Why does for loop exit for "" (empty string) in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

To explain my query I have a simple code snippet below followed by my question.

```
def count_vowels(s):
    num_vowels = 0
    for char in s:
        if char in 'aeiouAEIOU':
             num_vowels = num_vowels + 1
    return num_vowels

print(count_vowels(""))
print("" in "aeiouAEIOU")
```

gives an output

```
0 
True
```

**My doubt:**

Why does an empty string `""` returns `True` for the expression

```
"" in "aeiouAEIOU"
```

But it skips when it is present along with a for loop?

```
for char in s:
```

My understanding is that empty strings are a subset of all strings then why it is ignored when the same expression is in the for loop? Feel free to correct me if there is something I am missing here.

Comment: It contains no chars so the loop in `count_vowels` is exited immediately, eh?

Comment: @bipll That's fine but my question is why? Did you see the print expression? It returns True. So I am actually asking why the for loop skips a True expression ?

Comment: @mishsx the for loop isn't skipping a "True expression". Never once is `char == ''`. Iteration over strings is well defined, what were you *expecting*?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Okay so a follow-up question is that `char` is an iterator variable of the for loop and so I was expecting it to take the value of `""` and enter the for loop just once and cause the function to return 1

Comment: take a look on this docs:
[evaluate python empty string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5206466/why-empty-string-is-on-every-string#:~:text=Of%20course%20every%20substring%20of,equal%20to%20the%20empty%20string.&text=You%20can%20see%20%22python%22%20as,strings%2C%20...%22.)

Comment: @mishsx iteation over strings iterates over the characters in a string. The empty string, by definition, *has no characters*. It's entire purpose is to serve as an empty version of a string. I suppose, there could be a convetion, like, the last character of a string will always be an empty string, but there is not such convention, and I see little value for it. In any case, it is simply not how it is defined to work.

Comment: And note, I suppose `str` objects have the strange characteristic that iterating over them produces *objects of that same type*, since python does not have a "char" type, it is simply length-1 strings.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga That is totally fine. I know that is how it behaves in the interpreter as well. I was just curious as to how the same expression behaves differently with a for loop.

Comment: @mishsx when you evaluate this expression as an argument to print you get its boolean value which is `True`. When you evaluate it inside a body loop you don't evaluate it once as the body is never entered as the string iterated over is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression `"" in s` returns `True` for all strings `s`, because the empty string is trivially contained in all strings: the expression `A in B` is akin to asking the question ‘is there a pair of indices `i` and `j` such that `B[i:j] == A`’. If `A` is the empty string, we can always just set both `i` and `j` to zero, so the answer is yes.

However, iterating over code points of the empty string does not yield `""`, it yields nothing at all. Observe:

```python
def iterate(what):
    print("iterating over {}".format(repr(what)))
    for item in what:
        print("item: {}".format(repr(item)))
    print("iteration done")
    print()

iterate("abc")
iterate("")
iterate("")
```

The above code will print:

```text
iterating over 'abc'
item: 'a'
item: 'b'
item: 'c'
iteration done

iterating over ''
item: ''
item: ''
iteration done

iterating over ''
iteration done
```

In your example, the loop body will never run, so it will never increment the vowel counter.

Comment: That's an excellent example. Although the focus of my question is more towards how the expression `" in "aeiouAEIOU"` yields a True but not along with a for loop. However, from your example it seems it works differently with a for loop.

Answer (score 4):

Your understanding is correct: "empty strings are a subset of all strings"

But now let's see what happens when we use `for` for a sequence type such as string. Let's say we have:

```
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

for i in lst:
    print(i ** 2)
```

You can *just think* that it turns into:

```
index = 0
while True:
    try:
        i = lst.__getitem__(index)
    except IndexError:
        break
    print(i ** 2)
    index += 1
```

In your Example, when it tries to get even the first item, it will raise an Exception and break out of the loop. So it doesn't even go inside `For` loop.

I said "just think" because in for-loop, `iter()` is get called on the object (here `lst`) and this built-in function will get an iterator out of the object. In order this to be happened the object should implement either the iterable protocol which is either `__iter__` or it must support the sequence protocol (the `__getitem__()`)).

```py
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

it = iter(lst)
while True:
    try:
        i = next(it)
    except StopIteration:
        break
    else:
        print(i ** 2)
```

Both `str` and `list` object have `__iter__` so that is the method gets called rather than `__getitem__`. (`__iter__` has precedence over `__getitem__`)

Comment: So you mean to say there is a try-catch mechanism python has in its for loop implementation that causes the code to skip the loop ? If so your answer will be considered accepted. But it would help if you provide any documentation link for proof.

Comment: Yes, there is a try-catch mechanism, but it isn’t the one this post presents. Look up `StopIteration`.

Comment: @mishsx yes. best proof is, trying to implement a sequence type yourself. As you know you have to implement `__getitem__` method. Inside this function you have to somehow indicates that this is not a valid indices and in in order to do that, you raise an "IndexError" exception. But as a result you can see that it will be silenced  by python. how ? cause there is a try-except mechanism that "For" handles that for you. (as I mentioned in the answer)

Comment: @SorousHBakhtiary Thank you sir. Your answer is much aprreciated. It captures the essence of what I was looking for.

Comment: @mishsx happy to help. In case you wanna implement an Iterator, you have to do the almost same thing(`For` does something else with Iterators)  inside `__next__` method. Instead, you raise an StopIteration. At the end it will be silenced again by `For`.

Answer (score 3):

In the second print command you're asking does `""` appear in `"aeiouAEIOU"` and that is `True`.
However, the length of `""` is 0. So the for loop doesn't execute even once since there are no items to iterate over.

Comment: I am not asking for a fix. I am asking why the function `count_vowels("")` skips the for loop ? when the standalone expression `"" in "aeiouAEIOU"` is True in itself. Try debugging in Pyton vizualiser and see for yourself. I'm surprised this has not been asked before on Stack Overflow

Comment: Thanks for clarifying.Because the length of `s` is 0 so there's nothing to iterate over.

Comment: Going by the unanimous answers and comments, I will have to consider that the behaviour is by design. I was questioning the design all along and not the code.