# list.pop inside a for loop doesn't pop the last elements

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop

CODE :

```
stack = ['BOB','TOM','JAI','ALI','OM']
print(stack)

for i in stack:
    stack.pop()

print(stack)
```

OUTPUT :

```
['BOB', 'TOM', 'JAI', 'ALI', 'OM']
['BOB', 'TOM']
```

why does it stop after popping the last 3 elements? the list still has 2 elements left but it doesnt work for some reason

Comment: You should not modify the list while you are iterating over it.

Comment: @SorousHBakhtiary Is correct. You can loop over `range(len(stack))` instead to get the desired behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you modified the list while you are iterating over it.

If first iteration, Python gets the item at index `0` of the list,
If second iteration, Python gets the item at index `1` of the list,
etc.

The implicit counter variable that Python uses for getting items is incrementing...

Print your list in every iteration to see what is in it:

```py
stack = ['BOB', 'TOM', 'JAI', 'ALI', 'OM']

for i in stack:
    print(stack)
    stack.pop()

print(stack)
```

output:

```
['BOB', 'TOM', 'JAI', 'ALI', 'OM']
['BOB', 'TOM', 'JAI', 'ALI']
['BOB', 'TOM', 'JAI']
['BOB', 'TOM']
```

so :

```
In first iteration --> idx = 0 --> ['BOB', 'TOM', 'JAI', 'ALI', 'OM']
In second iteration --> idx = 1 --> ['BOB', 'TOM', 'JAI', 'ALI']
In third iteration --> idx = 2 --> ['BOB', 'TOM', 'JAI']
In forth iteration --> idx = 3 --> ['BOB', 'TOM'] --> Exit the loop here.
```

Solution:

```py
for i in stack.copy(): # Now you are iterating over a "copy" of the list
    stack.pop()
```

You could also do:

```py
for _ in range(len(stack)):
    stack.pop()
```

Comment: Since the element is not used in the loop, the copy is not necessary. looping over `range(len(stack))` is more efficient.

Comment: okay thanks! i guess thats just how python works but im just curious why the false loops occur when the container is being altered when we are iterating through it?

Comment: @PsyQuake I wrote an answer to another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64842523/13944524), but I think you will get your answer why. That `index` variable is independent of the loop's workflow.

Comment: @SorousHBakhtiary i see