# Why empty string in a non empty dictionary is true in python?

Tags: python, string, dictionary

I do not understand the logical idea of this behavior:

```
d = {'a': 'a',
     'b': 'b',
     }

print('' in d['a']) #---> True
print(d['a'] in '') #---> False
```

can someone help me?

Comment: This has nothing to do with the dictionary, In Python the empty string is inside any non-empty string

Comment: What does the dict have to do with it?

Comment: @wjandrea I think that's what was confusing the OP.  A common confusion thinking it would return false because '' is not in d.  (I'm just speculating)

Comment: That and the `in` operator is not commutative.

Comment: Did you mean to use `==`? `in` is almost never commutative. The only exception is when `==` is `True`.

Comment: @LPR Not really, OP is clearly doing `'' in d['a']`, not `'' in d`

Comment: @Deep Why did you remove [the duplicate I posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5206466/why-empty-string-is-on-every-string)? I saw [the one you added](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27603885/why-is-true-returned-when-checking-if-an-empty-string-is-in-another), but I thought the other one was more to-the-point.

Answer (score 2):

It's because it's searching the string 'a', if you ask if an empty string is in a non-empty string (or an empty string) it will return true.

What you are really asking is:

```py
'' in 'a'
```

```
Out: True  # Notice that 'a' is the same as '' + 'a'
```

---

```py
'a' in ''
```

```
Out: False
```